# RabbitMQ.Fakes Unit test C#, System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rabbitmq

I'm working with The message broker RabbitMQ and has setup a simple exchange and a queue waiting for JSON strings to be sent through.
I wish to unit test this, and has for this installed the nuget package 'RabbitMQ.Fakes' to create mock-ups to test my connections and so forth in.

So far I cannot do any checks on this because, when I hit the 'IConnection connection' line I get this error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'CreateBasicPublishBatch' of type 'RabbitMQ.Fakes.FakeModel' from assembly 'RabbitMQ.Fakes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not implemented.'

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestConnectionNotNull()
{
    FakeConnectionFactory factory = new FakeConnectionFactory();
    IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
}
```

Any ideas to what I can do to find the `CreateBasicpublishBatch` method and implement it? Or other ways to unit test RabbitMQ?

Comment: I've got the same issue! Did you find a work around?